# Where do Broadcom wireless drivers log?

Tags: broadcom, logging

I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 and I have a feeling that my laptop's Broadcom wireless drivers are the root cause of my machine crashing every so often without any reproducible reason. I'll spare you the details of my troubleshooting, but I'm almost **positive** its these wireless drivers.

Where would I find log output from these drivers directly, or from anything tangent to them? I ask so that the next time my machine crashes, I can go to those logs, view timestamps, and see if there are any dead giveaways. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer by Braiam is correct. For any other broadcom related issue please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx

Answer (score 1):

All system logs (in this case kernel modules) are logged in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/kern.log`, both are good leadings for your specific situation.